# Unable to find explicit activity class that isn't a class

Tags: android, android-manifest

Error looks for ShareARFrag that is not declared as activity, well because it is a fragment. I did change it to Fragment Activity and declare it, but it didn't work for me. So i changed it back to a Fragment and removed it from manifest, then there comes the error. Please help me. Thank you so much.

Here's the error:

```
05-07 08:52:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(32343): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.test1/com.example.test1.ShareARFrag}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

and here's my manifest:

```
.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_ars"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test1.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test1.BaseActivity"
            android:logo="@drawable/ad_logo"
            android:theme="@style/Theme1" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test1.FBShareDialog"
            android:theme="@style/TranslucentDialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test1.TweetShareDialog"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/TranslucentDialog" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your code. You might be trying to start the `Fragment`. You need to add the `Fragment` to your `Activity`

Comment: The fragment is good, it has been good before I added fb sharing. but seemed that fb sharing needs to be on an activity, i was wrong so i put it back on a fragment then the error came.

Comment: You have to show your code. Only then some one can help you to fix the problem.

Comment: Fortunately someone had the answer. Unfortunately i have to wait 6 minutes before i could put the check. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have code somewhere that is calling `startActivity()` with an `Intent` that specifies the `ShareARFrag` class. Instead, the `Intent` should be specifying the `Activity` that will contain that `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Explain what com.example.test1.ShareARFrag does? Is it an Activity or FragmentActivity?
Fragments can either be placed directly within XML or called by [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) to include into the current activity.

You might be calling something that does not exist.